# Group Data frame by unique values and mean

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm working with a data frame of 18 columns, with the working columns being CPM and SpendRange. Spend range is broken up into levels 1:3000 in steps of 50.

I'm trying to average the the CPM (Cost per Mil) within each spend range and result in a data frame with the unique spend ranges and the mean CPM in each.

I tried:

```
CPMbySpend<-aggregate(Ads$CPM,by=list(Ads$SpendRange),function(x) paste0(sort(unique(x)),collapse=mean(Ads$CPM))
    CPMbySpend<-data.frame(CPMbySpend)
```

Obviously finding out that I can't use the collapse as a function... any suggestions?

Optimum output would be:

```
  1-50   | mean(allvalues with spendrange 1-50)
  51-100 | mean(allvalues with spendrange 51-100)
```

Comment: Could you show a small reproducible example and expected result?

Comment: Absolutely, if the above collapse were replaced to collapse="," then the output would read: 

Group.1 | X
1-50    | 0.01,0.02,0.03,0.04......
51-100  | 0.05,0.06,0.07,0.08......

The intended result would be:
Group.1 | X
1-50    | mean(0.01,0.02,0.03...)
51-100  | mean(0.05,0.06,0.07...)

Does that help?

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing that trying to update to show more clearly. The objective would be two columns: Column A being the unique values of Ads$SpendRange, and Column B being the mean of all values in Ads$CPM. Think: Average Column B if Column A = 1-50 then put that value in a data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the new dataset

```
  Ads <- read.csv("Test.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  Ads$CPM <- as.numeric(Ads$CPM) #the elements that are not numeric ie. `-$` etc. will be coerced to NAs
  #Warning message:
  #NAs introduced by coercion 

  res <- aggregate(Ads$CPM,by=list(SpendRange=Ads$SpendRange),FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

If you want to order the `SpendRange` i.e `0-1`, `1-50` etc, one way is to use `mixedorder` from `gtools`.

```
  library(gtools)
  res1 <- res[mixedorder(res$SpendRange),] 
  row.names(res1) <- NULL
  head(res1)
  # SpendRange        x
  #1       0-1  1.621987
  #2      1-50  2.519853
  #3    51-100  3.924538
  #4   101-150  5.010795
  #5   151-200  3.840549
  #6   201-250  4.286923
```

Otherwise, you could change the order by specifying the `levels` of `SpendRange` by calling `factor`.i.e.

```
  res1$SpendRange <- factor(res1$SpendRange, levels= c('0-1', '1-50',.....)) #pseudocode
```

and then use

```
  res1[order(res1$SpendRange),]
```

Comment: I think this is close, I'm just getting the error: 
Error in do.call(Ads, aggregate(Ads$CPM, by = list(SpendRange = Ads$SpendRange),  : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function
In addition: There were 21 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: @GregdeLima I replaced that step `do.call` with new one. Are you still getting warnings().  As I mentioned before, better would be to post a reproducible example and your expected result so that there will be less confusion.

Comment: Yeah I'm still getting the error here is a link to the CSV I am reading into a dataframe: http://bit.ly/1pjVwyw

Comment: @GregdeLima The second column of your dataset contains  `$-`, so, when you read the file, it may be either character or factor column depending upon whether you used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE or TRUE`

Comment: You're 100% correct, my oversight in collecting data! Cleaned those up and the above suggestion worked great thank you!